# Is it possible to have multiple outputs using a ternary "if" statement in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble searching for this, so apologies if this has been asked before.

I'd like to have multiple outputs for a single-line if statement; i.e.

```
i > 2 ? print("true") AND ALSO i+=1 : print("false")
```

is this possible, or do I have to use the full if/else syntax to accomplish it?

Comment: The ternary should be used for simple statements else things get hard to read. Even then I'd only use it when you want to use the return value like `foo = i > 2 ? "this" : "that"`. I'd use an if/else for your code regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the expressions in parentheses like so:

```
i > 2 ? (print("true"); i+=1) : print("false")
```

Although I'd prefer using regular if/elses for longer-than-one-expression conditions. It's good for readability and as a programmer, I'd like good practice and readability over shortening the line.

Sacrificing readability and easy understanding for shorter code isn't a good tradeoff.

Comment: Ah, I knew it had to be that simple. Thank you. And thanks for the advice!